# How to import script from a folder at the same hierarchy level at which the main.py script is?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This might seem like a dumb question I found the answer to my question but it wasn't something I was looking for. So here I have a folder structure with scripts as follows:

```
project :
  -- main_scripts
     ---main.py
     ---test.py
  -- module_scripts
     __init__.py          # This method doesn;t work as to what I found.
     ---module1.py
     ---module2.py
```

I want to import the functions in the module1.py and module2.py in my main.py script but the only answers I found were based on sys.path.append or the PYTHON PATH ENVIRONMENT variable method. But those aren't the methods I am looking for. Is there any other way around to achieve this or these are the only possible options of method of module imports available in python

Answer (score 0):

`__init__.py` works for sub directories, and for the same hierarchy or parent directories you would have to import sys module and then append directory to sys.path, so the answer is no.